# I am trying to use jQuery/JavaScript to replace all <table>, <tr>, and <td> tags with <div> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, tags, html-table

I have `asp` auto generated code in an html template I am designing that use tables for its layout.  I would like to get rid of the tables and other layout features in a certain section of the page but I cannot directly change the actual html.   It needs to be a client side scripting solution and I am trying to use jQuery/JavaScript to replace all `<table>`, `<tr>`, and `<td>` tags with `<div>` tags and strip out all other layout, only leaving the content with the sections separated by div tags.  However I keep running into issues.  As I am not an expert in jQuery/JavaScript, any pointers/examples would be much appreciated.  Here is and example of the html code that is auto generated:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mainpage_features">
        <tr valign="middle">
            <td align="center" colspan="3">
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="featured_border_image">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="1%">
                            <img src="image.gif" border="0" />
                        </td>
                        <td width="98%" background="image.gif">
                        </td>
                        <td width="1%">
                            <img src="image.gif" border="0" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="1%" background=" box_left.gif">
                        </td>
                        <td width="98%">
                            <table class="feature_large" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <tr class="feature_large_title">
                                    <td rowspan="3" class="feature_large_image">
                                        <a target="_self" href="ResultsEvent.aspx?event=An+Event">
                                            <img class="feature_large_image" alt="Alt Text" src="anImage.jpg"></img></a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="feature_large_title">
                                        <a target="_self" href="ResultsEvent.aspx?event=An+Event">The Event</a><br />
                                        <img class="feature_large_title" src="feature_large_title.gif" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="feature_large_text">
                                    <td class="feature_large_text">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="feature_large_buynow">
                                    <td class="feature_large_buynow">
                                        <a target="_self" href="ResultsEvent.aspx?event=An+Event">
                                            <img alt="Buy Now" src="feature_large.gif" class="feature_large" /></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                        <td width="1%" background="box_right.gif">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="1%">
                            <img src="box_bottomleft.gif" border="0" />
                        </td>
                        <td width="98%" background=" box_bottom.gif">
                        </td>
                        <td width="1%">
                            <img src="box_bottomright.gif" border="0" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

(update)
As many have pointed out, JavaScript has problems.  I've found a CSS/html workaround.  Thanks.

Comment: So, basic rule of thumb for web development: Use HTML first, then CSS, and if you can't do what you want with those, then resort to JavaScript. Following this rule will nearly always produce better websites. I would say, if you cannot change the HTML itself, you probably shouldn't be doing this at all.

Comment: Why replace the tables? Don't break whats working right?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you did get something working, I would imagine the page load on the client would be quite slow, especially on older browser, as it would be doing a hell of a lot of DOM manipulation at page load.

Even to do this task by manually rewriting the HTML at the source is a PITA. Doing it programatically and writing something generic that would cover all various table layouts (valid or invalid HTML) would be a nightmare.

You could probably get something up and running pretty quickly for a simple example, but expanding it to a full site would be very painful.